# Xamarin Forms MessagingCenter or DependencyService

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to add a background task for location tracking. All the samples I've looked at use MessagingCenter to communicate between the PCL and platform components. So far, I've been using DependencyService's to communicate between PCL and platform. Is there a reason to use MessagingCenter for a background task instead of DependencyService?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I got your question right, but `Dependency Service` doesn't have to do really with background tasks or not. It's just an easy way to implement features in your project that require different handling in the native projects. So, for getting notified for async operations you should use `Messaging Center`.

Comment: When I receive a push notification, I raise an event on the dependency service interface from the platform project to notify the  PCL project of the notification.  Will that work with a background task (for other types of tasks) or does it have to be loosely coupled like with Messaging Center?

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to do something specific to each platform, and then have them post their results to a cross-platform place.

This is because when it comes to background collection of location, Android and iOS differ quite a bit. With iOS, you will likely have event handlers on some object which receive locations as they change according to the time and distance tolerances.

With Android, you will need to go with the Fused Location provider - Android 8 requires this. It is different in that for background, it will require setting a PendingIntent with the FusedLocationApi, which will be sent to your app when the location changes. In certain circumstances, these may be batched. For example, your app may be called ever 15 minutes with a collection of all the location changes that occurred during that time. You may be able to get around this with a "Foreground Service".

Be aware that this plugin: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin may only work correctly on Android if the service is implemented as a foreground service on Android 8.

I agree with @Greggz that messaging center vs dependency injection is more of an implementation choice to address platform specific implementations.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear.  I was not asking how to do location tracking.  Simply wanted to know if MessagingCenter was required for backgrounding.  Currently, my location tracking is using DependencyService to communicate between the platform code and the PCL.

Comment: The short answer is no. Backgrounding is platform specific, and thus orthogonal to MessagingCenter. MessagingCenter is *one way* of communicating and handling platform specifics.

Answer (score 0):

For the knowledge of all ...

This a good text from a Xamarin MVP that ilustrates good uses and misuses of MessagingCenter

I desagree in some point (I guess It is good because the systems are not coupled to each other) but could help you to understand the best use for it

https://xamarinhelp.com/common-misuse-messagingcenter/

Take a look

Regards

Guilherme